# Is there a way to make a register/login "database" using plain text and javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, authentication

I'm doing a project for school and i'm trying to implement a cross browser login script. I essentially want the registration to write to a plain text file the username and password while the login checks that plain text to see if it matches without the use of PHP or mysql. I am completely aware of how unbelievably stupid storing peoples logins with plain text is and that is what I want.

I currently have a system where it stores the information on your browser but it doesn't work cross browser and the account is not permanent. Code below -

```
function setupForm(){
    const form = document.getElementById("login-form");
    form.addEventListener("submit", handleSubmit);
}//setupForm

function handleSubmit(event){
    event.preventDefault();

    const {
        username,
        password,
        login_type,
        result
    } = event.target;

    const processUser = login_type.value == "register" ? registerUser : loginUser;
    const response    = processUser(username.value, password.value);
    result.innerHTML  = response;
}//handleSubmit

function registerUser(username, password){
    window.localStorage.setItem("exampleLogin__username", username);
    window.localStorage.setItem("exampleLogin__password", password);

    return `New user ${username} now registered!`;
}//registerUser

function loginUser(username, password){
    const registeredUser     = window.localStorage.getItem("exampleLogin__username");
    const registeredPassword = window.localStorage.getItem("exampleLogin__password");

    const validUser     = username == registeredUser;
    const validPassword = password == registeredPassword;

    if(validUser && validPassword){
        window.location.href = "benny/index.html";
    }
        else if(!validUser)     return `Username ${username} has not been registered. `;
    else if(!validPassword) return `Incorrect password for username ${username}`;
}//loginUser
```

This stores the information in the browser so it isn't permanent and doesn't work cross platform. I would like the javascript to write to the file and the other piece to read that file and check it.

Comment: Javascript is a client side script and cannot write anything on the server or user's computer (besides cookie or localStorage). What do you mean by doesn't work cross platform?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in order to persist the users data and make it available cross browsers, that data must live in some kind of a server that users communicate with when registering or trying to to login.
If your goal is just to not use a backend and you don't care about the security of these user data, you can just save and access it in a cloud stored file.
you can use for example http://myjson.com/api where you can save all your data into a json file, update it and access it with simple http requests you that you can do with jQuery

Comment: I'm using github to host the website, would I be able to store it in another file hosted in the same repo, if so, what would the code for something like that look like?

Comment: No, you **can't** access the file system using client-side javascript.

Comment: So if I were to do it the way you said off of myjson, what would the code for that be?

Comment: something like : ( for saving new data )
`
$.ajax({
        url: "https://api.myjson.com/bins/yourURL",
        type: "PUT",
        data: JSON.stringify(yourObject),
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data){
            console.log(data);
        }
      }); 
`
The link I posted above contains the whole documentation.
If you feel that this answer is helpful mark the question as solved.